# dynamic query for several date

Tags: t-sql

I wish to make a dynamic query for a set of dates, for example: 06/01/2015, 2015-07-01,2015-05-31, 30.04.2015 ... etc

I can do all these consultation date in one query:

```
select * from mytable
Where  DimtiempoId = 'date'.
```

I do not want is to make a query for each date. example:

```
select * from mytable
Where DimtiempoId = "01/06/2015".

select * from mytable
Where DimtiempoId = "01/07/2015".

select * from mytable
Where DimtiempoId = "31/05/2015".
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do.  Where is your set of dates coming from?

How about:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE DimtiempoId IN ('2015-01-06', '2015-01-07', '2015-05-31')
```

If your set of dates is coming from another table, you could do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE DimtiempoId IN (select mydate 
                      from setOfDates)
```

Comment: thanks friend, my  set of dates are parameters of a sp.

Answer (score 0):

thanks,
my set of dates are parameters of a sp.
To be more specific I save every result set in a table.
Example:

insert table1
select * from othertbl
where DimtiempoId= "01/06/2015"

insert table2
select * from othertbl
where DimtiempoId= "01/07/2015"

but I want to optimize my sp in a single query.